# IntelliJ Github Clone from Repository not working

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

I am trying to clone a project from a github repository by link. I do **File > Project from Version Control > Git** and it opens up the window. Testing the connection returns successful but when I press **Clone** nothing happens. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hey, I just tried this and it worked like a charm for me. What version of IntelliJ are you using? Also what is the repository that you are trying to clone? If it is a public repo, I could try and test cloning the repo itself.

Comment: I don't believe I can share it because it is a repository for a school project. My version of IntelliJ is Community Edition 2017.2.6 I think?

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried simply cloning using bash or terminal or a windows equivalent such a Git Bash and importing the project into IntelliJ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085

Answer (score 0):

What IDE version do you use? There used to be an issue with missing/wrong git client installed - Clone failed silently in that case - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135954

it has been fixed in the latest version and now IDE should provide a clear feedback.